# Pandas: Pivot table without sorting index and columns

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I'm trying to pivot data in a way so that the index and columns of the resulting table aren't automatically sorted. An example of the data might be:

```
X   Y   Z

1   1   1
3   1   2
2   1   3
4   1   4

1   2   5
3   2   6
2   2   7
4   2   8
```

The data is interpreted as an X, Y and Z axis. The pivotted result should look like this:

```
X   1   3   2   4
Y
1   1   2   3   4
2   5   6   7   8
```

Instead the result looks like this, where the index and columns are sorted, and the data accordingly:

```
X   1   2   3   4
Y
1   1   3   2   4
2   5   7   6   8
```

At this point I have lost information about the order in which the measurements were taken. For example say that I would plot the row at Y=1, with X as the X axis and the data value on the Y axis.

[This would result in the figures in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDa6z.jpg) On the right is how I would like the data to be plotted. Does anyone have an idea how to prevent pandas from sorting the index and columns when pivotting a table?

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative to *restore* the order, as the ordering is based on the **X** relative to **Y** values, for instance, you can restore your **X** columns ordering by something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# using your sample data
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df = df.pivot('Y', 'X', 'Z')

df
X  1  2  3  4
Y            
1  1  3  2  4
2  5  7  6  8

# re-order your X columns by the values of first Y, for instance
df = df[df.T[1].values]

df
X  1  3  2  4
Y            
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
```

Not the best approach, but sure it will achieve what you want.

Comment: I understand what you did, but I want the columns in the original order regardless of the Z values. The example I gave might not have been the best. Maybe I can retrieve the pattern `[1, 3, 2, 4]` from the X column and sort by that pattern, I'm trying to find out how but if you have an idea I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Ok I can retrieve the pattern by `df.groupby('Y')['X'].get_group(1).values`, and sort by those.